# Как изменить шрифт в Navigation Drawer (стандартный шаблон)?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer, шрифты, android-menu

В качестве пунктов там идет menu с item'ами, как можно поменять в них шрифт? Неважно программно или нет

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33540520/3212712):

1. Поместить файл шрифта в `assets` папку.
2. В методе создания меню загрузить шрифт
3. Использовать `TypefaceSpan` для создания строки с загруженным шрифтом
4. Установить строку со шрифтом в качестве заголовка пункта меню

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");    //  THIS
        TypefaceSpan face = new TypefaceSpan("<REPLACE_WITH_FONT_NAME>"); // OR  THIS 
        SpannableStringBuilder title = new SpannableStringBuilder(getContext().getString(R.string.edit));
        title.setSpan(face, 0, title.length(), 0);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_edit, 0, title); // THIS 
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit); // OR THIS 
        menuItem.setTitle(title);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: Вот тут похожее решение для `NavigationView` https://stackoverflow.com/a/30681846/3212712

Comment: Если шрифт уже встроен (sans-serif-light), решение аналогично?

Comment: @AndrewDmitriev, я думаю что да. Главное - как-то шрифт откуда-то загрузить.

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать библиотеку Calligraphy

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

По-умолчанию, она меняет шрифты во всем приложении, в т.ч. и в Navigation Drawer. Однако, изменить шрифт отдельно у какого-то элемента меню будет затруднительно